# Question on R programming with dplyr and tidy evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Folks I have a couple of questions about how tidy evaluation works with dplyr

The following code produces a tally of cars by cylinder using the mtcars dataset:

```
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  tally()
```

With output as expected:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
* <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

If I want to pass the grouping factor as variable, then this fails:

```
var <- "cyl"

mtcars %>%
  select(var) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  tally()
```

with error message:

```
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `var` is not found.
```

This also fails:

```
var <- "cyl"

mtcars %>%
  select(var) %>%
  group_by({{ var}}) %>%
  tally()
```

Producing output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"cyl"`     n
* <chr>   <int>
1 cyl        32
```

This code, however, works as expected:

```
var <- "cyl"

mtcars %>%
  select(var) %>%
  group_by(.data[[ var]]) %>%
  tally()
```

Producing the expected output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
* <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

I have two questions about this and wondering if someone can help!

1. Why does `select(var)` work fine without using any of the dplyr tidy evaluation extensions, such as `select({{ var }})` or `select(.data[[ var ]])`?
2. What is is about `group_by()` that makes `group_by({{ var }})` wrong but `group_by(.data[[ var ]])` right?

Thanks so much!

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how those functions work and accept input.

If you look at the documentation at `?select` the relevant part for this question is -

> These helpers select variables from a character vector:

> all_of(): Matches variable names in a character vector. All names must be present, otherwise an out-of-bounds error is thrown.

> any_of(): Same as all_of(), except that no error is thrown for names that don't exist.

So you can use `all_of` and `any_of` in `select` with character vectors hence you get a warning when you run `mtcars %>% select(var)`

> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
> ℹ Use `all_of(var)` instead of `var` to silence this message.

and no warning with `mtcars %>% select(all_of(var))`.

As far as `group_by` is concerned there is no such specific provision and you need to use `mtcars %>% group_by(.data[[var]])`.

Comment: And the FAQ for tidyselect mentions "This note will become a warning in the future, and then an error. We have decided to deprecate this particular approach to using external vectors because they introduce ambiguity. Imagine that the data frame contains a column with the same name as your external variable."